# Maven enforcer plugin is not enforcing

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

In pom I have parameter for one of the artifact id:

```html
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.abc.automation</groupId>
      <artifactId>${app}-xyz-extension</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

I intend to enforce any one using this pom to pass the param -Dapp ; for this I am using the enforcer plugin:

```html
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>enforce-property</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <requireProperty>
                    <property>app</property>
                    <message>
                      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                      You must set the app property!
                      This is used to determine which app is being tested and load the
                      corresponding extension.
                      Example: -Dapp=sampeapp
                      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    </message>
                    <!--<regex>.*\d.*</regex>-->
                  </requireProperty>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However this is not enforcing that the -Dapp needs to be base instead what i get is error from pom that

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for com.abc.automation:${app}-xyz-extension:test-jar with value '${app}-taas-extension' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 18, column 19

Plugins element is placed inside build as below:

```html
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
         ....
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Am i missing the basics of enforcer plugin?

Comment: Why do you have defined an artifactId with a property? What kind of problem do you have or trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise  This is used as a test runner. Different projects have their own artifact id. This test runner is agnostic and so can be used to run tests for any of the project (it's artifact id will be passed as parameter)

Comment: That make simply no sense cause dynamic project will not work...

Comment: Could you please explain more on this.it Is working fine except for this enforcers behavior.  @k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepak, it may be because of some other plugin/dependency that has placeholder ${app} written before enforce plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your plugin definition is inside `<pluginManagement>`. Move it to the `<plugins>` section of the POM.

Comment: yes, below is how the <plugins/> element is placed, is this an issue : 
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>

Comment: Even after the removal of plugin management i  still get: the maven complaint that artifactory id doesn't match.  
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for com.abc.automation:${app}-xyx-extension:test-jar with value '${app}-xyz-extension' does not match a valid id pattern.